# MongoDB - get max 3 values from collections

Tags: mongodb

I would like to ask you for help in finding the maximum dates (limit 3) from all groups.

```
    collection.aggregate([
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$flashcardCollection",
                "finalMaxDate": { "$max": "$sessionDate" }
            }, 
        },
        { "$sort": { "finalMaxDate": 1 } },
        { "$limit": 3 }
    ]).exec(function(error, fetchAllRecords){
        console.log(fetchAllRecords);
    });
```

my code finds only one maximum date in each group  even though the limit is set to 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { finalMaxDate: -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$flashcardCollection",
            finalMaxDate: { $push: "$finalMaxDate" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            finalMaxDate: {
                $slice: ["$finalMaxDate", 3]
            }
        }
    }
])
```